# Get Syntax Tree from SymbolAnalysisContext

Tags: c#, roslyn

I need to access the syntax tree (the complete source file text) from a given `SymbolAnalysisContext`. I found that I can call `context.Compilation.SyntaxTrees` but which one to pick from these? Is there another way?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A symbol can be defined in one or more SyntaxTrees, or in Metadata (by reference). You can get all of them via [ISymbol.Locations](http://source.roslyn.io/#Microsoft.CodeAnalysis/Symbols/ISymbol.cs,140), which:

> Gets the locations where the symbol was originally defined, either in source or
>    metadata. Some symbols (for example, partial classes) may be defined in more than one location.

If you're only interrested in the ones defined in your sources, you can do something like this:

```
var syntaxTrees = from x in context.Symbol.Locations
                  where x.IsInSource
                  select x.SourceTree;
```